# JSF How to dynamic add new row to datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I am currently doing an online test system, I want allow admin to create a test and add in few question. I was thinking using datatable add in coloumn with textarea? how can i add new row? or is there any other suggestion to implement add new more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned "admin", I think you probably mean you want to allow only users with certain rights to be able to add new question.

There are indeed more than one way to do it. It really depends on your requirements.

One example is you can add a [New Question...] `h:commandButton` in your page for users to navigate to another page for data entry. You may want to check whether the current user has the rights to navigate to the data entry page in the backing bean.

Then in the data entry page you have all your `h:inputText`, `h:inputTextArea` etc for users to enter their data/question. In this data entry page you can use a [Save] `h:commandButton` to submit the entered values, and then insert the submitted data in your backing bean.

If you preferred to use the add new row to datatable approach, BalusC has a very good write up in his blogspot http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html